# Are the google playground codes available offline

Tags: javascript

I am building simple visuals through Google APIs. Example of a script call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

1. Are these files available anywhere offline?
2. This is for a client, is this reliable enough to use or do you think Google could just pull access to these? (Leaving my company screwed...)

Comment: ... If that's a link to a file can't you just download it?

Answer (score 0):

It says in the documentation that you cannot download the code and it is not available offline...

Comment: Can you provide a link to and a quote from the relevant docs?